# Ableton sidechain track to EQ band gain?

Tags: ableton-live, ableton, side-chaining

I'm curious how I can utilize a track with kicks to duck a specific frequency band in my main track.

I can split the main track with Multiband Dynamics, and duck the middle band, but is there any way to simply route to a param like one of the EQ 8 points?

Comment: What version of Ableton Live do you got ?

Comment: latest edition with suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is:

1. Duplicate the layer you wish to do this on
2. on one layer EQ everything **EXCEPT** the frequencies you want to duck
3. on the other layer **ONLY** EQ the frequencies you want to duck
4. side-chain your kick to the second layer (the one with **ONLY** the frequencies that you want to duck)

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Just realized thats what chain in instrument racks is for XD thanks